# Make compatible two different pieces of code

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So, am creating a game where a spaceship moves and must avoid one fireball in order to win. However I would like to have many fireballs and I managed (after hours) to get this following piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<style> img {position: absolute}</style>

<body id="body"></body>

<script>
const fireballArray = [];
function generateFireBallWithAttributes(el, attrs) {
for (var key in attrs) {el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key])}
return el}
function createFireBalls(amount){
for (let i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
fireballArray.push(
generateFireBallWithAttributes(document.createElement("img"), {
src: "Photo/fireball.png", width: "36"}))}}
createFireBalls(7)
fireballArray.forEach((fireballElement) => {
const fallStartInterval = setInterval(function(){})
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(fireballElement)
const fireball = {x: fFireball(fireballElement.offsetWidth), y: 0}
const fireLoop = function() {
fireball.y += 1
fireballElement.style.top = fireball.y + "px"
if (fireball.y > window.innerHeight) {
fireball.x = fFireball(fireballElement.offsetWidth)
fireballElement.style.left = fireball.x + "px"
fireball.y = 0}}
fireballElement.style.left = fireball.x + "px"
let fireInterval = setInterval(fireLoop, 1000 / ((Math.random() * (125 - 75)) + 75))})
function fFireball(offset) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - offset))}
</script>
</html>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328402/add-multiple-images-video-game-js

So I would like that someone could try to put together those two pieces of code (you can also give me another solution for code n°1).

I know it is not a very good question but I really need to end this game so if anyone of you can help me it would be REALLY appreciated. Thanks.

Ps: As previously said you can give me another solution for adding fireballs

Comment: If you need to create firewalls, you can use the `HTML DOM cloneNode() Method` on the HTML element holding your "firewall". In this way, you don't have to go over the whole creating process and your code might become smaller. When your firewall gets out of the screen or "extinguish", don't delete the element. Just hide it and move it to the origin. You will obtain more FPS in this way since you are saving the time to recreate a reusable element.

Comment: _"I would like that someone could try to put together those two pieces of code"_ — Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Please use spaces/tabs for formatting the code. It looks terrible. Also, don't you wanna use a canvas for the game?